# Port 445 between Sharepoint and DC

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2013

We would like to set up a SharePoint farm (1 DC, 3 SharePoint server and 1 SQL -Server)  in the DMZ.
The IT-Security pointed out,
that the port 445 between SharePoint server and DC is a security risk.
Does SharePoint 2013 server really need this port?
Is there any work around to avoid using this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid disabling port 445 - you will give yourself a lot of headache if you do that.  Port 445 is used by the CIFS, SMB, RPC, DFS, and Netlogon major services, plus a few more minor ones.  Netlogon in particular controls the secure channel between client machine, member servers and domain controllers and is a requirement for a properly functioning Active Directory, as mentioned in this article:  [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and in this one: [Network Ports Used by Key Microsoft Server Products](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875824.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  To answer your question, SharePoint 2013 requires this port, and there is no Microsoft-sanctioned workaround to avoid port 445.  To be sure, even if you did, you would *have* to put those services on some other port.